# md Input lable is not properly aligned

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

[image: Angular Material Form]

I am referring [Angular Material Input](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples)  example.

Package and Version :

- "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11",
- "@angular/core": "4.1.2"

  1. Firstly I added dependencies in app.module like

```
     import { MdInputModule, MdCheckboxModule } from "@angular/material";
     .
     .
     .
     .
     imports [
          MdInputModule,
          MdCheckboxModule,
     ], ..
```

2. Created component like sample.component.ts (SampleComponentClass) and sample.component.html.
3. register SampleComponentClass in app.module
4. Snippet of HTML Code

   `<md-form-field class="example-full-width">
         <input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
    </md-form-field>
    <md-checkbox>Check me!</md-checkbox>
    <button md-raised-button>Submit</button>`

Question is :

1. Input tag placeholder should be properly inlined (check packageId input box - without value)
2. Input tag placeholder should go up if value is there but it is not working as this (check Favourite food input box - with value)

Comment: Please do not post two questions in the same question.

Comment: Also, what's your Angular version?

Comment: create fiddler or similar snippet of your code

Comment: @VicJordan OP should use Stackblitz instead. This is for Angular Material, **not** AngularJS Material, the older framework.

Comment: Please use the proper syntax for a code block: 4 spaces before the code.

Comment: @Edric I tried but it is rendering the code, using 4 block space. also tried ctrl + k. but no change. finally i used inline code block.

Comment: @Ronnie Looks like Angular Material requires Angular **4.4.5 and greater**.

Comment: tried with higher version. But no luck. I think this is not the issue.